# Active Record association has_many with multiple foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to set up a referral model. A referral contains a user who is referred, a user who does the referring, and a doctor

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :referrals
  belongs_to :profile, polymorphic: true
end

class Referral < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :referrer, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :doctor, :class_name => "User"
end
```

I'm able to create the generic `has_many :referrals` to see doctors that have been referred to the user however I'd also like to see the doctors that you've referred to others (using the `referrer` column).

I've tried `has_many :doctors_referred, primary_key: "referrer_id"` and `has_many :doctors_referred, through: :referrals ,source: "referrer"` with no luck. How can I see which doctors a user has referred?

```
# mostly irrelevant 
class PatientProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :profile
end

class DoctorProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :profile
end
```

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt would be this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :referrals_as_referrer, source: :referred
  has_many :referrals_as_referree, source: :user

  has_many :doctors_as_referrer, through: :referrals_as_referrer
  has_many :doctors_as_referree, through: :referrals_as_referree
end
```

The issue here is that saying `has_many :referrals` isn't enough because you can have a referral where you were the referrer or one where you were the referree. With this you can type `user.referrals_as_referrer` which will give a list of referrals where `user` is the referrer. You can also write `user.doctors_as_referrer` which will go through the previous association and retrieve a list of users that represent doctors which were referred by a referral in the `user.referrals_as_referrer` list.

I haven't tested this and I might be wrong, but let's iterate once you try it out.

Comment: thanks, I'll give it a whirl tonight and let you know

Comment: still getting `NameError: uninitialized constant User::ReferralsAsReferrer`